# Can't catch node-opencv errors?

Tags: node.js, exception, opencv, try-catch

I'm trying to catch errors thrown by node-opencv (native bindings) instead of crashing the process.

https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv

I've tried using a `try{}catch(){}` block and using `process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) {});` neither had any effect, the process still crashed when an error was thrown.

example: `libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

This question refers to any opencv error that gets thrown, not one in particular.

Can I put all of my node-opencv into their own process -- then run that as a child process of my main process. When it crashes, restart it and keep going?

Comment: node-opencv is very ugly module inside, and looks like it does not catches own exceptions, so you can't do really much. Unless you want to dive into module, and change its code (add C exception handling) and then recompile with node-gyp.

Comment: Could you put in your post how to reproduce the error?

Comment: @hexacyanide This isn't for a specific error, it's for any error thrown by this lib. Errors can be produced many ways, just pass in a bad buffer or something.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs Please see EDIT 2 and let me know if you think this would work. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can use cluster and worker process. But as you realize it might have complications when you need to clear up some media, or finish of some algo but it will be lost, so you will like start from clean.
It will work generally if errors are rare occasions.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html)

> Domains provide a way to handle multiple different IO operations as a
>   single group. If any of the event emitters or callbacks registered to
>   a domain emit an error event, or throw an error, then the domain
>   object will be notified, rather than losing the context of the error
>   in the process.on('uncaughtException') handler, or causing the program
>   to exit immediately with an error code.

### Okay you don't like my previous answer, so here is another one:

http://snmaynard.com/2012/12/21/node-error-handling/

http://benno.id.au/blog/2011/08/08/nodejs-exceptions

> The other option is to use the event system provided by node.js. That
>   is what we will look at next as it is what node.js uses internally. We
>   are going to change our code so that y emits a myerror event rather
>   than the exception bubbling up.

```
var events = require('events')
emitter = new events.EventEmitter()

function y(arg, callback) {
    if (arg === 1) {
    x()
    callback()
    } else {
    function onTick() {
        try {
        x()
        } catch(err) {
        emitter.emit('myerror', err)
        return
        }
        callback()
    }
    process.nextTick(onTick)
    }
}
```

Events called error are treated very specially by the node code. From the emit code in event.js:

```
  if (type === 'error') {
    if (!this._events || !this._events.error ||
        (isArray(this._events.error) && !this._events.error.length))
    {
      if (arguments[1] instanceof Error) {
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
      } else {
        throw new Error("Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event.");
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```